# Not able to refer to data table in power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create a Pareto chart in Power BI.
The steps I have done so far are as follow.
I have created a DATATABLE using the following (short version below as there were over 400 entries in the table ). The data table is used as a lookup to find specific values in a string.

```
DATATABLE (
    "Code", STRING,
    {
        {"DI0001"},
        {"DI0002"},
        {"DI0003"},
        {"DI0004"},
        {"DI0005"},
        {"DI0102"},
        {"DI0103"},
        {"DI0104"}])
```

The issue that I have with my data is that the DI codes are placed in one column. Each row can have a different number and different types of DI code. that is why I have used the measure below to check the strings in each row and calculate the sum of each DI code. Additionally, I have posted a picture of the data I'm working with.[image]

```
VAR __SearchTerms =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
       'Table',
        "Count",
            COUNTROWS (
                FILTER (
                    'DI_Report',
                    FIND ( [Code], 'DI_Report'[DI Codes],, 0 ) > 0
                )
            )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( __SearchTerms, [Count] )
```

Once I have used the above measure in a table visual putting it in as Value and putting the [code] form the data table as value as well. I have revised the following result.
[image]

The above was satisfying so far but I'm having an issue with the next step
As the next step, I want to create the cumulative of the 2nd column and cumulative showed as %.
So the cumulative value for the second code will be the sum of the values for the first and second code. the cumulative for the third code is the sum of values for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd code and so on. the cumulative % would e similar just showed as a percentage of the total sum.

In excel it looks like this
[image]

I was trying the following measure to get the cumulative DI column but I'm not able to refer to the input table. I'm receiving an error "The column 'Code' specified in the 'SUMMARIZE' function was not found in the input table."

```
VAR StateRev = [DI Codes Total]

RETURN
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE(ALLSELECTED(DI_Report), 'Table'[Code],
            "Cumulative", [DI Codes Total]),
                [Cumulative] >= StateRev ),
                    [Cumulative])
```

I'm really new to power bi, and the above is used from other threads and instruction videos I managed to find. I'm not sure if the above is the best way to do what I need. If someone knows a better way to approach this I'm open for suggestions

Could someone please support me with this one, broad explanations would be much appreciated.
If you require any additional details I'm happy to share them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. The above code was referring to the wrong table. After fix, it looks like

```
Cumul = VAR StateRev = [DI Codes Total]

RETURN
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE(ALLSELECTED('DI_Code'[Code]), [Code],
            "Cumulative", [DI Codes Total]),
                [Cumulative] >= StateRev ),
                    [Cumulative])
```

additionally, I used the following to get the value for the Pareto chart

```
 Pareto Chart (DI) = 
VAR StateRev = [DI Codes Total]
VAR ALLCodes = CALCULATE([DI Codes Total], ALLSELECTED(DI_Code[Code]))
RETURN
DIVIDE(
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE(ALLSELECTED('DI_Code'[Code]), DI_Code[Code],
            "Cumulative", [DI Codes Total]),
                [Cumulative] >= StateRev ),
                    [Cumulative]),
    ALLCodes, 0)
```